# Execution of Laravel Queue listener for undefined time

Tags: laravel-5, queue

I'm working on a system that needs run multiple works but the time when this works will be triggered it's undefined. I've implemented a couple of Jobs in order to run this works in background because some of them take up to 20 minutes.

My question is:

- It is ok to let the queue listener run with a timeout=0?
  If the answer is no, what is the best practice to resolve this problem?

Thanks for your help.